# MySQL query to get SUM and merged results from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having 3 tables in my MySQL DB. The Tables and columns are like in sample below

Table `User`

```
id, name,  dob,       gross_salary
----------------------------------
1,  test1, 12 Mar 90, 50000
2,  test2, 10 Jan 85, 45000
```

Table `Wage`

```
ida, date,      allowence_paid
------------------------------
1,   10 Jul 13, 12000
2,   10 Aug 13, 23000
2,   12 Aug 13, 1000
1,   15 Aug 13, 15000
```

Table `Loan`

```
id, date,      loan_amount
--------------------------
2,  05 Jul 13, 500
1,  05 Aug 13, 2500
1,  06 Aug 13, 1200
```

I need these three tables merged in results for Aug 13 like

```
id, name,  allowence_paid, loan_Amount, paid
--------------------------------------------
1,  test1, 15000,          3700,        11300
2,  test2, 24000,             0,        24000
```

SUM of two columns from two different tables joined to another table  is required in my case.

Can I get help for the query? I have experimented as per [MySQL JOIN with SUM and 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040948/mysql-join-with-sum-and-3-tables) and failed.

Comment: It's called `join`. You have those in a couple of flavors, of which `inner join` and `left (outer) join` are most commonly used.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL JOIN with SUM and 3 tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040948/mysql-join-with-sum-and-3-tables)

Comment: You should know that even if people know the answer, they are reluctant to help when you have not shown any effort at all. And this feels like homework to me. We are here to HELP you, not to COMPLETE your homework.

Comment: I am expecting help from experts. Not assigning any home works to beginners. I have experimented as per link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040948/mysql-join-with-sum-and-3-tables and failed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
select *, allowence_paid-loan_amount as paid
from
(
select User.id as UserId, User.name as UserName, sum(allowence_paid) as allowence_paid
from Wage join User on Wage.ida=User.id 
and Wage.date between '2013-08-01 00:00:00' and '2013-08-31 23:59:00'
  group by UserId
) W JOIN
(
select User.id as UserId, User.name as UserName, sum(coalesce(loan_amount,0)) AS   loan_amount 
from Loan right outer join User on Loan.id=User.id 
and Loan.date between '2013-08-01 00:00:00' and '2013-08-31 23:59:00'
group by UserId
) L ON W.UserId = L.UserId
```

SQL fiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94a14/37).

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much 'NEUTRINO'.